# How do I show members their current status on CiviCRM/WordPress

Tags: wordpress, civimember

I'm unable to show our members their specific membership status info as I keep getting the "Profile search, view and edit are not supported"

Why is it so hard for CiviCRM to have a simple feature that allows members see their current status and decide to renew or not on their own?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE!  Your question has been down-voted probably because of your choice of wording.  We prefer a more neutral or positive approach such as 'How can I ...' rather than 'Why is it so hard to ...'  Some things are hard, but you'll find the community is pretty good at providing help and advice if asked in the right way.

Answer (score 4):

Its not so hard - there are a few ways to do this.

Easiest - create a user dashboard page where a user can see all of their account history.

`[civicrm component="user-dashboard" hijack="0"]`

On the dashboard - there is also an option to renew.

[image: Membership Example]